# Kubernetes - Reconfiguring a Service to point to a new Deployment (blue/green)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, blue-green-deployment

I'm following along with a video explaining blue/green Deployments in Kubernetes. They have a simple example with a Deployment named *blue-nginx* and another named *green-nginx*.

The blue Deployment is exposed via a Service named *bgnginx*. To transfer traffic from the blue deployment to the green deployment, the Service is deleted and the green deployment is exposed via a Service with the same name. This is done with the following one-liner:
`kubectl delete svc bgnginx; kubectl expose deploy green-nginx --port=80 --name=bgnginx`

Obviously, this works successfully. However, I'm wondering why they don't just use `kubectl edit` to change the labels in the Service instead of deleting and recreating it. If I edit *bgnginx* and set *.metadata.labels.app* & *.spec.selector.app* to *green-nginx* it achieves the same thing.

Is there a benefit to deleting and recreating the Service, or am I safe just editing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `kubectl edit` is that it requires a human to operate a text editor.  This is a little inefficient and things do occasionally go wrong.

I suspect the reason your writeup wants you to `kubectl delete` the Service first is that the `kubectl expose` command will fail if it already exists.  But as @HarshManvar suggests in [their answer](/a/75505646), a better approach is to have an actual YAML file checked into source control

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    example.com/deployment: blue
```

You should be able to `kubectl apply -f service.yaml` to deploy it into the cluster, or a tool can do that automatically.

The problem here is that you still have to edit the YAML file (or in principle you can do it with `sed`) and swapping the deployment would result in an extra commit.  You can use a tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh) that supports an extra templating layer

```yaml
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    example.com/deployment: {{ .Values.color }}
```

In Helm I might set this up with three separate Helm releases: the "blue" and "green" copies of your application, plus a separate top-level release that just contained the Service.

```bash
helm install myapp-blue ./myapp
# do some isolated validation
helm upgrade myapp-router ./router --set color=blue
# do some more validation
helm uninstall myapp-green
```

You can do similar things with other templating tools like [ytt](https://carvel.dev/ytt/) or overlay layers like [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/).  The Service's `selectors:` don't have to match its own metadata, and you could create a Service that matched both copies of the application, maybe for a canary pattern rather than a blue/green deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can follow the `kubectl edit svc` and edit the **labels & selector** there.

it's fine, however **YAML** and other option is suggested due to **kubectl edit** is **error-prone** approach. you might face **indentation** issues.

> Is there a benefit to deleting and recreating the Service, or am I
> safe just editing it?

It's more about following best practices, and you have YAML declarative file handy with version control if managing.